# Regex not matching decimal format

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations

I am trying to make a post to my api controller, passing as parameter CoordinateModel class

```
public class CoordinateModel
{
    [Range(-90, 90)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{6}$")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [Range(-180, 180)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{6}$")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Using this JSON as request body

```
{ "Latitude": 12.345678, "Longitude": 98.765543 }
```

When I try to validate the model with `ModelState.IsValid` is saying the model is not valid. This is the resposne I get on Postman

```
{
"Latitude": [
    "The field Latitude must match the regular expression '^\\d+\\.\\d{6}$'."
],
"Longitude": [
    "The field Longitude must match the regular expression '^\\d+\\.\\d{6}$'."
]
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my Regex. My Latitude/Longitude must have at least one digit before the decimal separator and contain 6 decimals digits

Comment: Longitudes and latitudes can be negative, you should allow for that. Why are you doing string validation on a number? Just validate it as a number (which, you are doing with the range). And, requiring ecact 6 digits after the decimal point seems odd. Somehow I don't think you get six digits at Greenwich, England.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReqularExpression-annotation is validating the parsed double value, not the input value. This makes your code dependent on the region settings as it calls .ToString() before validating it.

I'd recommend either changing the field to string and parsing it later on (maybe in a getter or setter) or not validating the number of digits - otherwise you will block api-users that pass something like "98.76554" instead of "98.765540" (what is an issue even with the trailing zero if you keep your current code). You also might implement a custom validation if you need to.

It will fail if something not-parseable is passed anyways.

See the [post from SBFrancies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51459803/3085985) for code to proof this behavior.

Comment: You're right! I am in Brazil and the default separator is `,`. Changing the regex to validate with `,` or `.` it works fine. Thanks for pointing this out. And don't worry about api users, this is not a real application.

Comment: Ok glad I could help, just be aware that it will also fail for every number ending with a 0, so make sure that's ok for your "not a real application" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Compufreaks answer, I tried manually validating your code in a Console app and it worked fine so it is likely that the problem are down to how the doubles is being parsed.

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CoordinateModel model = new CoordinateModel {Latitude = 12.345678, Longitude = 98.765543};

        var vc = new ValidationContext(model);
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, vc,null, true); //isValid == true

        var json = "{ \"Latitude\": 12.345678, \"Longitude\": 98.765543 }";

        model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoordinateModel>(json);
        vc = new ValidationContext(model);
        isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, vc, null, true); //isValid == true
    }
}

public class CoordinateModel
{
    [Range(-90, 90)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{6}$")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [Range(-180, 180)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{6}$")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code on my machine and isValid is false. If I replace the `.` with a `,` in the validation code it works. This is because in my german region settings `,` is the decimal seperator - so yes, your code proves my theory, thanks for that.

Comment: Oh and as a side note, isValid is also false if you put `98.765540` instead of `98.765543` as input - that should also happen with your regional settings and shows another issue with this kind of validation.